# label for attribute changes color of label

Tags: html, colors, label

I used 'for' attribute in label tag in HTML but using that made my lable look grey rather than default black help me to make this black uniformly without using any inline style or giving any special class attribute in each label.

Comment: can you show us an example of the mark up and css that is causing your issue?

Comment: As far as I know giving a label a `for` attribute should not have any effect on its appearance. Do you think there could be something else going on here?

Comment: sorry my bad i went wrong, this question is wrong please scrap from system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just change the style all labels.

```
label {
color: #000; /* makes the text-black */
}
```

of you can make it more specific...

```
#form-id-here label {
color:#000;
}
```

That way you can change the labels for a certain form only.